# Como eliminar todos los caracteres especiales al copiar y pegar un texto

Tags: php, javascript, html

Tengo una función para que elimine los caracteres especiales como:

! " # $ % & / () = ? ¡ ' ¿ : ;

Si elimina algunas pero otras no, por ejemplo hice una prueba al copiar un texto de word lleno de caracteres especiales y la mayoría del texto lo limpia pero lo que no quita son las comillas dobles (" ") esas se siguen quedando y también encontré que al copiar y pegar texto de word me pone unas comillas diferentes que son estas (“ ”) y al querer cambiar estas comillas por espacio o eliminarlas no hace nada, las sigue dejando, también en el documento encontré que los  tres puntos (...) también los sigue dejando y al querer enviar la información y al pasar por el PHP no lo deja porque no estoy admitiendo esos tres puntos y tampoco las comillas.

Esta es la función en JS para eliminar los caracteres especiales:

```
function limpiarDesc(texto){
var texto = texto.toLowerCase();
texto = texto.replace(/[!]/, "");
texto = texto.replace(/[#]/, "");
texto = texto.replace(/[$]/, "");
texto = texto.replace(/[%]/, "");
texto = texto.replace(/[&]/, "");
texto = texto.replace(/[/]/, "");
texto = texto.replace(/[(]/g, "");
texto = texto.replace(/[)]/g, "");
texto = texto.replace(/[;]/g, "");
texto = texto.replace(/[:]/g, "");
texto = texto.replace(/[<]/, "");
texto = texto.replace(/[>]/, "");
texto = texto.replace(/[']/, "");
texto = texto.replace(/['"]+/g, "");
texto = texto.replace(/”/g, '');
texto = texto.replace(/“/g, '')
return texto;
}

$(".mensaje").change(function(){

$(".LimpiarMensaje").val(limpiarDesc($(".mensaje").val()));

})
```

Esto es mi PHP por si algún carácter se llega a pasar o quieren afectar la aplicación, tener protección por el lado del servidor:

```
if(preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9ñÑáéíóúÁÉÍÓÚ ]+$/', $datos["titulo"])
        && preg_match('/^[,\\.\\a-zA-Z0-9ñÑáéíóúÁÉÍÓÚ ]+$/', $datos["LimpiarMensaje"])
        && preg_match('/^[^0-9][a-zA-Z0-9_]+([.][a-zA-Z0-9_]+)*[@][a-zA-Z0-9_]+([.][a-zA-Z0-9_]+)*[.][a-zA-Z]{2,4}$/', $_POST["correo"])){
```

Y lo que e notado es que el problemas son las comillas que me trae el word (“ ”) y los tres puntos (...), porque al quitar eso del texto con el que estoy probando si inserta la información en la base de datos, por alguna razón el JS no detecta estos caracteres para eliminarlos.

Este es el HTML:

```
<form role="form" method="post">

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="input-group">
            <div class="input-group-prepend">
                <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fas fa-at"></i></span>
            </div>
            <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg correo" name="correo" id="correo" placeholder="Nunca compartiremos su correo electrónico con nadie más" required>
                    </div>
                </div>

        <div class="form-group">
          <div class="input-group">
            <div class="input-group-prepend">
              <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fas fa-pencil-alt"></i></span>
            </div>
            <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg titulo" name="titulo" id="titulo" placeholder="Título" required>
                </div>
            </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="input-group">
            <div class="input-group-prepend">
                <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fas fa-comment"></i></span>
                </div>
            <textarea type="text" rows="3" class="form-control input-lg mensaje" name="mensaje" id="mensaje" placeholder="Descripción" required></textarea>
                            </div>
                        </div>

          <input type="hidden" class="form-control input-lg LimpiarMensaje" name="LimpiarMensaje" placeholder="" readonly>

        <button type="button" class="btn btn-info mb-4 consulta btn-block"><h2>Crear Consulta</h2></button>

    </form>
```

Lo que queremos con esto es que el usuario no batalle, que solo copie y pegue el texto a su gusto y ya nosotros nos encargamos de limpiarlo y que no nos lleguen afectar la aplicación.

Este seria un ejemplo al copiar y pega el texto:

```
SENTENCIA. LOS CONSIDERANDOS DE ÉSTA, RIGEN A LOS RESOLUTIVOS Y SIRVEN PARA 
INTERPRETARLOS. Cuando existe discrepancia entre un considerando de una 
sentencia y un resolutivo de la misma, debe entenderse que los considerandos 
rigen a los resolutivos y sirven para interpretarlos; y, por ende, los 
argumentos de la sentencia, por sí mismos, no causan agravios al quejoso, 
cuando éstos no han conducido a la ilegalidad de la resolución reclamada.
•   No. Registro: 184,403 Jurisprudencia Materia(s): Común Novena Época 
Instancia: Tribunales Colegiados de Circuito Fuente: Semanario Judicial de 
la Federación y su Gaceta Tomo: XVII, Abril de 2003 Tesis: XX.1o. J/62 
Página: 1026
•   PRIMER TRIBUNAL COLEGIADO DEL VIGÉSIMO CIRCUITO.
•   Véase: Apéndice al Semanario Judicial de la Federación 1917-1995, Tomo 
VI, Materia Común, página 331, tesis 501, tesis de rubro: "SENTENCIAS. SU 
AUTORIDAD SE EXTIENDE A LOS CONSIDERANDOS.".
ACLARACIÓN DE SENTENCIA FISCAL. ES IMPROCEDENTE SU DESECHAMIENTO POR EL 
MAGISTRADO INSTRUCTOR. En términos del artículo 239-C del Código Fiscal de 
la Federación, la aclaración de sentencia que se promueva se reputará como 
parte integrante de la sentencia que emite la Sala Fiscal, por lo cual dicha 
instancia debe ser resuelta por la propia Sala y no desecharse de plano por 
el Magistrado instructor, aun cuando estime de manera individual que del 
escrito respectivo se advierta la notoria improcedencia de la solicitud de 
aclaración, ya que los autos que dicta el citado Magistrado, por constituir 
actos decisorios de índole unitaria, no pueden formar parte de las 
sentencias de la Sala resueltas de manera colegiada y, por tanto, a él sólo 
compete darle el trámite correspondiente a la aclaración promovida.
•   No. Registro: 188,331 Tesis aislada Materia(s): Administrativa Novena 
Época Instancia: Tribunales Colegiados de Circuito Fuente: Semanario 
Judicial de la Federación y su Gaceta Tomo: XIV, Diciembre de 2001 Tesis: 
VI.1o.A.113 A Página: 1670
•   PRIMER TRIBUNAL COLEGIADO EN MATERIA ADMINISTRATIVA DEL SEXTO CIRCUITO.
•   Amparo en revisión 416/2000. José de Jesús Miranda Espinosa. 26 de 
septiembre de 2001. Unanimidad de votos. Ponente: Jorge Higuera Corona. 
Secretario: Enrique Cabañas Rodríguez
```

Este seria el texto ya limpio:

```
SENTENCIA. LOS CONSIDERANDOS DE ÉSTA, RIGEN A LOS RESOLUTIVOS Y SIRVEN PARA 
INTERPRETARLOS. Cuando existe discrepancia entre un considerando de una 
sentencia y un resolutivo de la misma, debe entenderse que los considerandos 
rigen a los resolutivos y sirven para interpretarlos y, por ende, los 
argumentos de la sentencia, por sí mismos, no causan agravios al quejoso, 
cuando éstos no han conducido a la ilegalidad de la resolución reclamada.
•   No. Registro 184,403 Jurisprudencia Materia Común Novena Época 
Instancia: Tribunales Colegiados de Circuito Fuente: Semanario Judicial de 
la Federación y su Gaceta Tomo: XVII, Abril de 2003 Tesis: XX.1o. J/62 
Página: 1026
•   PRIMER TRIBUNAL COLEGIADO DEL VIGÉSIMO CIRCUITO.
•   Véase Apéndice al Semanario Judicial de la Federación 1917-1995, Tomo 
VI, Materia Común, página 331, tesis 501, tesis de rubro SENTENCIAS. SU 
AUTORIDAD SE EXTIENDE A LOS CONSIDERANDOS..
ACLARACIÓN DE SENTENCIA FISCAL. ES IMPROCEDENTE SU DESECHAMIENTO POR EL 
MAGISTRADO INSTRUCTOR. En términos del artículo 239-C del Código Fiscal de 
la Federación, la aclaración de sentencia que se promueva se reputará como 
parte integrante de la sentencia que emite la Sala Fiscal, por lo cual dicha 
instancia debe ser resuelta por la propia Sala y no desecharse de plano por 
el Magistrado instructor, aun cuando estime de manera individual que del 
escrito respectivo se advierta la notoria improcedencia de la solicitud de 
aclaración, ya que los autos que dicta el citado Magistrado, por constituir 
actos decisorios de índole unitaria, no pueden formar parte de las 
sentencias de la Sala resueltas de manera colegiada y, por tanto, a él sólo 
compete darle el trámite correspondiente a la aclaración promovida.
•   No. Registro 188,331 Tesis aislada Materias Administrativa Novena 
Época Instancia Tribunales Colegiados de Circuito Fuente Semanario 
Judicial de la Federación y su Gaceta Tomo: XIV, Diciembre de 2001 Tesis 
VI.1o.A.113 A Página 1670
•   PRIMER TRIBUNAL COLEGIADO EN MATERIA ADMINISTRATIVA DEL SEXTO CIRCUITO.
•   Amparo en revisión 416/2000. José de Jesús Miranda Espinosa. 26 de 
septiembre de 2001. Unanimidad de votos. Ponente Jorge Higuera Corona. 
Secretario: Enrique Cabañas Rodríguez
```

Lo que solo aceptaríamos serian los puntos, las comas, los números y los acentos.

Comment: quieres que elimine todos los caracteres que no sean numeros  y letras?

Comment: Si, para que no pasen caracteres especiales a la base de datos

Comment: podrias agregar a tu pregunta un texto problematico y como deseas que salga!

Comment: Ya puse los ejemplos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Que tal hombre, espero te pueda servir de algo, o al menos te de una mano.***

En cuanto a **PHP**, yo uso esto:

```
//Aquí colocas los caracteres que no quieres que pasen    
$arrayCharactersNotAllowed = array("£","¥","è","ù","ì","ò","Ç","Ø","ø","Å","å","Æ","æ","ß","¤","¡","ä","ö","ü","à","Ü","Ö","Ä");
$arrayErroneousButAllowedCharactersQuotes = array('‘','’','“','”');//Esta línea es lo de las comillas que genera WORD
$arrayErroneousButAllowedCharactersEllipsis = array('…','—');//Esta línea es para los puntos supensivos que genera WORD

//Aquí reemplazamos por los caracteres que queremos que pasen, o simplemente los eliminamos
$content = str_replace($arrayCharactersNotAllowed,'',$content);
$content = str_replace($arrayErroneousButAllowedCharactersQuotes,'"',$content);
$content = str_replace($arrayErroneousButAllowedCharactersEllipsis,'...',$content);
```

---

Y en cuanto al **Javascript** puedes simplificar tu método agrupando todos los caracteres en  una sola sentencia, pues, para que no repitas tantas veces **texto = texto.replace(/[!]/, "");**, de esta forma:

```
texto.replace(/['"!#%$&/();:<>....etc]/g,'');
```

Comment: Gracias por responder Fernando, nada mas para entender el código, donde va la variable $content ahí pondría mis variables? Bueno mejor dicho, como le digo que variable trae el el contenido que tiene que revisar

Comment: Exactamente @sagitor, $content, en este caso sería la variable que contiene el texto o la cadena a analizar para eliminar los caracteres inválidos. Por ejemplo: $content='Hola$% esto " es ! el /{ contenido a = ? ana¿lizar+';

Comment: Muchas gracias @FernandoChamorro me funciono a la perfección el código.

Comment: Ok, vale. Me alegro que lo hayas podido solucionar: (Y)

Answer (score 0):

puedes hacerlo asi con una expresion regular que solo acepte letras y numeros:

- \w - coincidan [a-zA-Z0-9_]+
- \s - espacios
- \r - retorno de carro
- \n - salto de linea

  echo preg_replace("/^[\w.\n\r\s]+$/", "", $str);